Android webview file upload only works once if aborted
Scenario
I have an Android app with a WebView.
The WebView is displaying a web page with a simple file upload control. The simplified code is:
<input id="photoupload" type="file" />

This HTML renders as expected in the WebView, showing a "Choose file" button. Tapping the "Choose file" button will initiate file selection successfully.
Problem
If the file selection is then aborted without selecting a file, tapping on the "Choose file" button again will no longer initiate file selection. It appears to do nothing. The upload control will no longer work.
Question:
Is there a native HTML / JS solution that I can implement in the web page, that will keep the "Choose file" button working after file selection has been aborted?
I have seen solutions involving adding code to the WebView. But I have no access to the Android app for this. I can only alter the displayed web page.
